# Could not create unique index - claims to have duplicate values but it doesn't

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to create a unique index on code field:

```
$ CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "one_code_per_person" on "core_person"("code") WHERE "code" IS NOT NULL;
ERROR:  could not create unique index "one_code_per_person"
DETAIL:  Table contains duplicated values.
```

It says there are duplicate values but:

```
$ select code, count(*) from core_person group by code having count(*)>2;
code | count 
-----------+-------
(0 rows)
```

- which proves there are not.

WTF?

Comment: Actually, count(*)>1 would be the condition you need to test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

...means there needs to be 3+ duplicates.  You want to use:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

...to find records with 2+ duplicates.